# Window confirm message before reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is working fine but I was just wondering if this is normal.. I tried my code in Linux and my confirmation message before exiting the page or reloading can be altered. However when I tried it on my Mac the only message that I saw was "Changes you made may not be saved". Is it because of the code or because of the OS that the message is behaving like that. It occurs whether in Chrome of Firefox

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="TestApp">
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('TestApp', [])
.factory('beforeUnload', function ($rootScope, $window) {
    // Events are broadcast outside the Scope Lifecycle

    $window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        var confirmation = {};
        var event = $rootScope.$broadcast('onBeforeUnload', confirmation);
        if (event.defaultPrevented) {
            return confirmation.message;
        }
    };

    $window.onunload = function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('onUnload');
    };
    return {};
})
.run(function (beforeUnload) {
    // Must invoke the service at least once
});
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.$on('onBeforeUnload', function (e, confirmation) {
        confirmation.message = "All data willl be lost.";
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $scope.$on('onUnload', function (e) {
        console.log('leaving page'); // Use 'Preserve Log' option in Console
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="TestController">
This is a test
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**PS**

The code above is AngularJS but even the same functionality with the use of pure javascript behaves the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine.

[The reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Notes) states that

> In Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user. Instead, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."

It also states that 'Custom text support removed' in Chrome 51.0 and Firefox 44.0.

Comment: So that's answer it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have another problem when I reload the system. The 'onUnload' does not do anything. I tried alerting but nothing happened

Comment: @estus Is there a work around to show a custom message to the user when he closes the browser?

Comment: @R.S.K I guess the answer is no, at least I'm unaware of it.